Upgrading from 22.04 to 23.04
Upgrades to the development release are only
available from the latest supported release.

Ubuntu 23.04 is end of life (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/) so upgrades to it are not possible.  Could you perhaps want to upgrade to 24.04 LTS?  which isn't supported in regards release-upgrade yet as per status page  (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-24-04-release-status-tracking/44043) with it only being expected (for 22.04 to 24.04) after 24.04.1 release just like prior LTS releases.
